# Handling killed process in Android/Linux kernel.

Tags: android, c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have an android kernel specific question. Can someone explain what exactly happens when a process is killed in the kernel. I want to handle all such processes within my modified kernel. I have a hunch this should be handled somewhere in /kernel/exit.c .

Does anyone have a clearer idea as to what exactly happens in such an incident and where to handle this ?

Comment: Would something like this help ? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-process-management/

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+process+lifecycle

Comment: How exactly do you want to "handle" them differently than the kernel does by default?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart- By returning an error in my functionality implemented in the kernel. Also be freeing all memory attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a SIGKILL is delivered to the process the same way as other signals but when the task handles the signal (in kernel mode before resuming userspace execution), it would check the signal number and terminate the thread group if it's SIGKILL.
For linux kernel(I'm not familiar with Android) you may want to check out "kernel/signal.c"